# IPC message queue overflow consequences

Tags: c, embedded, ipc, openwrt

I am creating a C application, which will be executed in openwrt router device. Because of limited resources I'm a bit scared about the message queue. What if the "reader" application, which takes the messages from the queue, crash and the "writer" still sends the messages? Should I be worried about the device's memory or will the message queue clean itself eventually?

EDIT I realised that I wasn't clear enough about my task. One application will be sending messages and other will be reading and processing them.

Comment: What type of message queue?

Comment: System V IPC. For that I'm using <sys/msg.h> library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation for `msgsnd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html):

> The queue capacity is governed by the msg_qbytes field in the associated data structure for the message queue.  During queue creation this field is initialized to MSGMNB bytes, but this limit can be modified using msgctl(2).

> If insufficient space is available in the queue, then the default behavior of msgsnd() is to block until space becomes available.  If IPC_NOWAIT is specified in msgflg, then the call instead fails with the error EAGAIN.

So the sender will wait for the receiver to process a message, unless you use `IPC_NOWAIT`, in which case it returns `EAGAIN` and the sender can check for this error code.

The default maximum buffer size is specified in a constant called MSGMNB. You can print this value to see what it is on your system. To change the maximum size for your queue, you can use the function `msgctl`.